# How to extract name of the current sheet in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm still a noob to Rstudio. I have a spreadsheet with two dozen sheets in the file. I know that the R command getSheetNames() would return a list of all the sheets in my Excel file. However, I would like to get the name of the current sheet that I'm working on. What command should I use for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. Generally Excel makes it hard for other programs to access a file as you are editing it.

Comment: "Perhaps" you could use `statconnDCOM` (a package, not on CRAN) to access Excel's exported COM api on windows. I'm not holding my breath (no idea if it's still being supported), but it's a thought. Otherwise ... I think the answer is likely "not possible" (or at best "not at all easy").

Answer (score 1):

`openxlsx::activeSheet()` provides the active sheet of an Excel file.

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("Book1.xlsx")

sheets(wb)
#> [1] "Sheet1" "Sheet2"
activeSheet(wb)
#> [1] 2

sheets(wb)[activeSheet(wb)]
#> [1] "Sheet2"
```